# Exam Parts Alignment

Tags: exam, parts

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\RequirePackage{xspace, setspace}
\printanswers

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\singlespacing

\parindent 0ex
\begin{document} 
    \begin{questions}
        %\newpage
        \addpoints
        \question[15] Here's the question.
        \begin{parts}
            \part What's the solution for part a?
            \begin{solution}
                Here's the solution for part a.     
            \end{solution}
            \part What's the solution for part b?
            \begin{solution}
                Here's the solution for part b.     
            \end{solution}
        \end{parts}
        Hint: Here's the hint for part b. %Want to put in parts while retaining margin
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Output: 
[image]

Is there a way to get the hint part of the code inside the `parts` while retaining the margin originally for the `questions` environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `\uplevel` command (or `\fullwidth` if the hint should use the whole width of the exam).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\RequirePackage{xspace, setspace}
\printanswers

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\singlespacing

\parindent 0ex

\begin{document} 
    \begin{questions}
        %\newpage
        \addpoints
        \question[15] Here's the question.
        \begin{parts}
            \part What's the solution for part a?
            \begin{solution}[12in]
                Here's the solution for part a.     
            \end{solution}
            \part What's the solution for part b?
            \uplevel{Hint: Here's the hint for part b.}

            \begin{solution}
                Here's the solution for part b.     
            \end{solution}
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]